# CSS changes ignored when config.assets.debug = true in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, sass, asset-pipeline

I am trying to solve the absolutely ludicrous view refresh delays when changing any CSS settings in my Rails 4.2.5 development environment.

The only thing that really works is changing this setting in my development.rb, as recommended by several web sources:

```
config.assets.debug = false
```

This supposedly will speed things up, and it certainly does (90 seconds for a simple reload vs 10 seconds), but now any changes I apply to my CSS stylesheets are ignored. I have to revert back to config.assets.debug=true and restart my server in order to SEE any CSS changes.

Is this normal?

I find that it is becoming more and more frustrating to develop in rails due to this view refresh delay issue.

These are the contents of my development.rb file:

```
Rails.application.configure do
  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: '$IP', port: $PORT }
  # Settings specified here will take precedence over those in config/application.rb.
  require 'carrierwave/orm/activerecord'
  #to be able to render console in cloud9
  config.web_console.whitelisted_ips = '0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0'
  # In the development environment your application's code is reloaded on
  # every request. This slows down response time but is perfect for  development
  # since you don't have to restart the web server when you make code changes.
  config.cache_classes = false

  # Do not eager load code on boot.
 config.eager_load = false

  # Show full error reports and disable caching.
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = true
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = false

  # Don't care if the mailer can't send.
  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true

  config.action_mailer.smtp_settings ={
    :user_name => ENV['SENDGRIDUSERNAME'],
    :password => ENV['SENDGRIDPASSWORD'],
    :domain => 'deseocumplido.pe',
    :address => 'smtp.sendgrid.net',
    :port => 2525,
    :authentication => :plain,
    :enable_starttls_auto => true
  }

  # Print deprecation notices to the Rails logger.
  config.active_support.deprecation = :log

  # Raise an error on page load if there are pending migrations.
  config.active_record.migration_error = :page_load

  # Debug mode disables concatenation and preprocessing of assets.
  # This option may cause significant delays in view rendering with a large
  # number of complex assets.
 config.assets.debug = false

  # Asset digests allow you to set far-future HTTP expiration dates on all assets,
  # yet still be able to expire them through the digest params.
  config.assets.digest = true

  # Adds additional error checking when serving assets at runtime.
  # Checks for improperly declared sprockets dependencies.
  # Raises helpful error messages.
  config.assets.raise_runtime_errors = true

  #lets serve images outside public folder (example tmp images when uploading)
  config.serve_static_files = true
  # Raises error for missing translations
  # config.action_view.raise_on_missing_translations = true
end
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Almost a year later what mostly worked to avoid these delays was avoiding imports and using requires in my asset pipeline (js and css), as explained here: http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/tale-front-end-sanity-beware-sass-import. Rails is usable again.